# UIAlertAction dismisses the UIAlertController in its callback

Tags: swift, ios8, uialertcontroller

I am trying to use new `UIAlertController` introduced in iOS 8. Everything works great except the fact that `UIAlertAction` always end up dismissing the alert controller in its callback. Following is my code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Group", message: "Enter Group name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ [weak self] (nameField: UITextField!) in
    nameField.becomeFirstResponder();
    nameField.delegate = self;
    return;
})
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default, handler: { action in
    println("Done Entering");
}));
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil));
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Now, when I click "Done" button, the controls enters the callback method and then alert is dismissed even though I don't have any statement to dismiss the alert. Is this behavior by default? If yes, how can I make sure that in some cases the alert stays on the screen (depending upon my conditions)? Am I missing something here?

I would really appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, alert buttons **always** dismiss the alert and there is no way to configure them otherwise. If you want that behavior, you'll have to write your own alert. I've written [SDCAlertView](http://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView), which looks very much like a normal alert, but has some added functionality, including prevention of dismissing an alert when a button is tapped.

However, it doesn't use the `UIAlertController` API yet and it looks a little bit different (most users won't notice) on iOS 8 than the `UIAlertController` alert.

**EDIT:** It now has support for the `UIAlertController`-like API.